# TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8732

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I have a wcf service application using windows service.  Additionally, I have a wpf app that connects to the wcf service.  I have been unable to open the wpf program. This is the error I get when I attempt to open the wpf app from Visual Studio by hitting F5 in debug mode:

```
mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/NextGenService/SimSession/. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:02.2590000. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8732.
```

I do have both Http and Non-http activation options on under the wcf activation node of selected features.  all 3 services to do with net.tcp are running: Net Pipe Listener Adapter, Net.Tcp Listener Adapter, Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service.

app.config for the server:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="logFile" value="C:\ProgramData\SimSci\Log\server.log"/>
    <add key="SecureFolder" value="..\..\..\..\..\SharedComponents"/>
    <!--<add key="logLevel" value="Debug"/>-->
    <!--<add key="VariableConnection" value="Connected"/>-->
  </appSettings>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <!--Add below switch when need trace on developer system  -->
      <!--switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing"-->
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging"  switchValue="Off">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type=""/>
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
            <filter type=""/>
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <!--Add below switch when need trace on developer system  -->
      <!--switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing"-->
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Off" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type=""/>
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
            <filter type=""/>
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="..\..\app_messages.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
        <filter type=""/>
      </add>
      <add initializeData="..\..\app_tracelog.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
        <filter type=""/>
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>


  <!-- tempdt timeout values-->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_ISimSession" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="104857600" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="104857600" maxArrayLength="104857600" maxBytesPerRead="104857600" maxNameTableCharCount="104857600"/>
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false"/>
          <!--<security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>-->
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service name="SimCentral.Server.SimSession">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_ISimSession" contract="NextGenServices.Contract.ISimSessionService.ISimSession">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/NextGenService/SimSession/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <gcServer enabled="true"/>
    <gcConcurrent enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

app.config for the client

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ContractType" value="ISimSession"/>
    <add key="ISimSessionNameSpaceVersion" value="http://Invensys.com/SimSci-Esscor/NextGen-Sim/1.0.32.6e"/>
    <add key="Scope" value="aa.soa://SimSession"/>
    <add key="UseASBHost" value="0"/>
    <add key="logFile" value="C:\ProgramData\SimSci\Log\client.log"/>
    <add key="logLevel" value="Debug"/>
  </appSettings>


  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_ISimSession" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="true" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="104857600" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="104857600" maxArrayLength="104857600" maxBytesPerRead="104857600" maxNameTableCharCount="104857600"/>
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"/>
          <!--<security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>-->
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/NextGenService/SimSession/" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_ISimSession" contract="SimSessionService.ISimSession" name="NetTcpBinding_ISimSession">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

I tried all the suggestions on the Internet, but none is working for me. Is there anything else that I can do to fix this problem ? Thank you.

Comment: @spender if it were firewall, most probably the client would time out. TCP error says that there is no listening process..

Comment: Don't you have to add an IIS binding for those TCP endpoints? I'm not sure.

Comment: @spender: firewall should not be a problem. I already set the port number 8732 on windows firewall to allow communication.

Comment: @all: I figured it out. I have to setting up both of 2 solutions (the client and server) as startup projects in order to call the program. Thanks for your help guys

Comment: IIS Binding: Open IIS -> Sites -> Default Website {right click} -> Edit Bindings -> Select type: net.tcp and Binding information: 8732:*

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue.

Please check your windows service OnStart method for following line.

```
serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(**WCFService**));
```

Make sure this WCFService is actually you WCF service contract class and not the windows service class. There are posts over the internet which creates this ServiceHost for windows service and not WCFService, which is not correct.

Comment: There are hundreds possible reasons for an HTTP call to fail. Not starting the HTTP service is one of many. Also, if you try to start a ServiceHost on a non-WCF class or interface, you'll get an exception telling you that.

Comment: I believe the question was related to net.tcp binding and not http binding? Why are you explaining about HTTp failures?

Comment: Replace HTTP with TCP, whatever. The point is, you're not answering the question. The question is _"Why does **my** code not work"_, it's not _"List all possible reasons for this code to fail"_. Your answer shows one of many possible, and awefully specific causes for this problem, basically stating _"Make sure the WCF Service is running"_.